# Install MediaWiki on subdomain pointed to folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mediawiki

I installed a MediaWiki on `example.com/wiki` at first. It works as expected. Then I created a subdomain `wiki.example.com` and pointed it to `example.com/wiki`, and now only `index.php` works, all pages returns me 404.

Here is my `LocalSettings.php`

```
# This file was automatically generated by the MediaWiki 1.24.1
# installer. If you make manual changes, please keep track in case you
# need to recreate them later.
#
# See includes/DefaultSettings.php for all configurable settings
# and their default values, but don't forget to make changes in _this_
# file, not there.
#
# Further documentation for configuration settings may be found at:
# https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings

# Protect against web entry
if ( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
    exit;
}

## Uncomment this to disable output compression
# $wgDisableOutputCompression = true;

$wgSitename = "MyWiki";

## The URL base path to the directory containing the wiki;
## defaults for all runtime URL paths are based off of this.
## For more information on customizing the URLs
## (like /w/index.php/Page_title to /wiki/Page_title) please see:
## https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL
$wgScriptPath = "/wiki";
$wgScriptExtension = ".php";

## The protocol and server name to use in fully-qualified URLs
$wgServer = "http://example.com";

## The relative URL path to the skins directory
$wgStylePath = "$wgScriptPath/skins";

## The relative URL path to the logo.  Make sure you change this from the default,
## or else you'll overwrite your logo when you upgrade!
$wgLogo = "$wgScriptPath/MyWiki-logo-colorida.png";

## UPO means: this is also a user preference option

$wgEnableEmail = true;
$wgEnableUserEmail = true; # UPO

$wgEmergencyContact = "apache@example.com";
$wgPasswordSender = "apache@example.com";

$wgEnotifUserTalk = false; # UPO
$wgEnotifWatchlist = false; # UPO
$wgEmailAuthentication = true;

## Database settings
$wgDBtype = "mysql";
$wgDBserver = "localhost";
$wgDBname = "wiki";
$wgDBuser = "user";
$wgDBpassword = "pass";

# MySQL specific settings
$wgDBprefix = "";

# MySQL table options to use during installation or update
$wgDBTableOptions = "ENGINE=InnoDB, DEFAULT CHARSET=binary";

# Experimental charset support for MySQL 5.0.
$wgDBmysql5 = true;

## Shared memory settings
$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_NONE;
$wgMemCachedServers = array();

## To enable image uploads, make sure the 'images' directory
## is writable, then set this to true:
$wgEnableUploads = false;
$wgUseImageMagick = true;
$wgImageMagickConvertCommand = "/usr/bin/convert";

# InstantCommons allows wiki to use images from http://commons.wikimedia.org
$wgUseInstantCommons = false;

## If you use ImageMagick (or any other shell command) on a
## Linux server, this will need to be set to the name of an
## available UTF-8 locale
$wgShellLocale = "en_US.utf8";

## If you want to use image uploads under safe mode,
## create the directories images/archive, images/thumb and
## images/temp, and make them all writable. Then uncomment
## this, if it's not already uncommented:
#$wgHashedUploadDirectory = false;

## Set $wgCacheDirectory to a writable directory on the web server
## to make your wiki go slightly faster. The directory should not
## be publically accessible from the web.
#$wgCacheDirectory = "$IP/cache";

# Site language code, should be one of the list in ./languages/Names.php
$wgLanguageCode = "pt-br";

$wgSecretKey = "my_secret_key";

# Site upgrade key. Must be set to a string (default provided) to turn on the
# web installer while LocalSettings.php is in place
$wgUpgradeKey = "upgrade_key";

## For attaching licensing metadata to pages, and displaying an
## appropriate copyright notice / icon. GNU Free Documentation
## License and Creative Commons licenses are supported so far.
$wgRightsPage = ""; # Set to the title of a wiki page that describes your license/copyright
$wgRightsUrl = "";
$wgRightsText = "";
$wgRightsIcon = "";

# Path to the GNU diff3 utility. Used for conflict resolution.
$wgDiff3 = "/usr/bin/diff3";

# The following permissions were set based on your choice in the installer
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;

## Default skin: you can change the default skin. Use the internal symbolic
## names, ie 'vector', 'monobook':
$wgDefaultSkin = "vector";

# Enabled skins.
# The following skins were automatically enabled:
require_once "$IP/skins/CologneBlue/CologneBlue.php";
require_once "$IP/skins/Modern/Modern.php";
require_once "$IP/skins/MonoBook/MonoBook.php";
require_once "$IP/skins/Vector/Vector.php";


# End of automatically generated settings.
# Add more configuration options below.

# Disable reading by anonymous users
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;

# But allow them to access the login page or else there will be no way to log in!
# [You also might want to add access to "Main Page", "Wikipedia:Help", etc.)
$wgWhitelistRead = array ("Special:Userlogin");

# Disable anonymous editing
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;

# Prevent new user registrations except by sysops
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;

require_once "$IP/extensions/Mantle/Mantle.php";
require_once "$IP/extensions/MobileFrontend/MobileFrontend.php";
$wgMFAutodetectMobileView = true;   

$wgEnableUploads = true;
```

How can I do for my wiki works well accessing it by `wiki.example.com`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgScriptPath
>
> $wgPath is The base URL path (in relation to DOCUMENT_ROOT)

It sounds like you've configured "/wiki" to be your DocumentRoot.

SUGGESTIONS:

1) Configure your web server to point to the directory *above* "wiki"

... OR ...

2) Configure your "$wgPath" to "/"

Comment: Your 2) doesn't work for me, I just tried it. Your 1)... I tried it earlier today, but I'm gonna try it again.

Comment: This worked for me:

$wgPath = '/';
$wgScriptPath = "/wiki";

... and actually this is your 2), and I don't know why it's working now. Thanks.